# How to get markers for Google map api for places for categories such as hill station, forest, mangrove etc around my current location?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I tried using google map api for

> radar search

Results were quite big than actual. How do I get these markers?

Comment: Are you use PlacesService API? Try `keyword` option.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer which fulfills my requirement:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=new+york+city+point+of+interest&language=en&key=API_KEY

API key should be generated from developer's console using

> Google Places API Web Service

You can always verify the same from Google Map directly by using the same keywords.